# Kubernetes: How to restart services after os patch

Tags: kubernetes

We have traefik service running as below:

```
~]$ netstat -pante | grep LIST | grep -w 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          82345      12345/traefik
```

After the os patch the services on most ports including this was killed.

```
~]$ netstat -pante | grep LIST | grep -w 443
~]$
```

Nothing is running now.

When the pods are trying to run they are unable as nothing is listened on this port.

```
traefik-ingress-controller-92cd7              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   408        184d
traefik-ingress-controller-cxvtq              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          12m
```

I want to restart the "traefik" service, how do I do? I **do not** want to restart PODS, that I know, want to restart the service.

Does apply will restart/start the service? i.e.

```
kubectl apply -f <traefik-ingress-controller.yaml>
```

will restart service? if not, what is the way to restart?

To add few things.

As explained prior this was the process, up and running.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep traefik
root     12345 11222  0 Mar01 ?        00:27:20 traefik traefik --configfile=/config/traefik.toml
```

Hence the netstat (above) shows this process/service is listening to 443 port.

Now, I cannot see anything
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep traefik

I am trying to restart this.

I tried:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart containerd

sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

Even after all this ,traefik is not running and port 443 is not listening to anything.

One this in the controller see this error.

```
= 'traefik' is not a Traefik command: assuming shell execution.
```